# For loop run in two arrays

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new in python and I was wondering the following.
I have two matrices g1 and g2 and I would like to run a for loop for all the values of g1 and then g2.

I initially thought I could do:

```
for A in g1:
   .....

for A in g2:
   .....
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to run both at the same for loop.
Eg. I tried this but it didn't work

```
for A in g1,g2:
```

Comment: Look at `zip`:  https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to iterate on two lists at once.

```
one = [1,2,3,4]
two = [5,6,7,8]
for elem1, elem2 in zip(one, two):
    print(elem1, elem2)
```

Prints out this:

```
(1, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 7)
(4, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate both iterables at the same time:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
for x, y in zip(l, l2):
    print x, y

1 4
2 5
3 6
```

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check the two data in the two loop is independent. Then you could merge  the two loop in one.